# c++ entity component system and accessing components using a template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, components, entity-component-system

I've been working on creating my own entity component system, and I'm set on being able to get a component by doing the following:

```
const auto& component = entity->GetComponent<ComponentType>();
```

The above function would then look something like this:

```
template <typename TyComponent>
TyComponent* Entity<T>::GetComponent() const
{
  return &(GetComponent(TyComponent::Id());
}
```

Which then returns a component based on the associated id if found, else `nullptr`.

1. Is what I'm doing viable?
2. Is there a way to ensure only types derived from Component can be
   used as a parameter for `GetComponent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design is OK.

You'll already get a compile time error if anyone tries `GetComponent<Foo>`, but `Foo` doesn't have a static `Id()` function. So that gives you a bit of safety.

However, it still needs one change to compile. Here's how I'd do it:

```
Component * GetComponent(int id) { ... }

template <typename TyComponent>
TyComponent* Entity<T>::GetComponent() const {
  return dynamic_cast<TyComponent*>(GetComponent(TyComponent::Id()));
}
```

This will now generate a compile error when `TyComponent` is not derived from `Component`. (Component will need at least one virtual function for this to work though.)

Comment: Wouldn't a `static_cast<Component*>` be sufficient for a compile time check?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You're correct. In this case, you can get away with a `static_cast` but I prefer the extra safety of getting a NULL rather than getting undefined behaviour, should something be wrong...